# Animate letter with css and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

**HERE'S MY [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/gp3puwc2/25/)**

I have animation on my text when you hover them images.

But I would like to apply more effect on these texts (h1).

I showed you an exemple on my JSFIDDLE with the text "What I want" (you have to reload the page to see the effect)

I would like to apply the effect of the text "What I want" on the other h1 text. (01-One, 02-Two and 03-Three)

But it doesn't work.

**JQUERY :**

```
$('h1').lettering();

$('h1').children().each(function(i){
  var letter = $(this);
  setTimeout(function(){
    //alert('yo');
    letter.addClass('fadeBounceIn')
  }, i*50)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gp3puwc2/28/) I made. I think it's pretty close to what you're trying to do.

The problem is that the lettering `bounce-in` effect you have only occurs one time when the page loads. So all of your `h1`'s were getting animated just fine, but they were not animating again when you scroll.

I simply took that code and put it into a function like this:

```
var lettering = function() {
$('h1').lettering();
$('h1').children().each(function(i){
  var letter = $(this);
  setTimeout(function(){
    //alert('yo');
    letter.addClass('fadeBounceIn')
  }, i*50)
});
}
```

And then inside of your scroll function I simply added a call to the `lettering()` function I created.

Finally, I've made an assumption that you still want it to happen on page load so I've simply added this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
lettering();
});
```

Which will call the function on the initial page load.

You may need to play around with things a little bit to get your specific desired effect.

Comment: Thanks maxshuty ! The problem is that the "bounce effect" of the letters appears after few seconds, and before this moment you have a bounce effect on the whole sentence. How can I disable this first bounce effect ? I would like this effect only on the letters